Stable-baselines3 how to impose policy action_space different than environment action_space
Normally, with eg. sac policy, you would have observations -> sac -> actions -> environment. But because i want to have observations -> sac -> extra_block -> actions -> environment, I am in a situation where the SAC action_space will be different than the environment action_space (actual command sent to the env).
Initially, I just started with a wrapper around SAC, and change in its init function the SAC action_space to what I want. However, that means i have to change the replay_buffer, the policy, the actor action_spaces etc and it starts to look ugly and patchy.
Isn't there a way to just send the desired action_space to SAC, to overwrite the baseclass sac.action_space + env.action_space? I saw that the policy classes have the action_space as arguments, but how to get there from the SAC wrapper, without changing any of the sb3 code or my separate environment.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
